# what jquery isArrayLike checks nodeType

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a function named 'isArrayLike' in jquery which used by many functions for example $.each

```
function isArraylike( obj ) {
var length = obj.length,
    type = jQuery.type( obj );

if ( type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
    return false;
}

if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length ) {
    return true;
}

return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
    typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
```

}

I know it is used to see whether it is like an array,but i do not know why the second if.

It checks nodeType to make sure it's an element and why length?Is an element have length property?

Thx

Comment: If the passed object is an element, then the method is returning true, the [NodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) 1 is for Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find undocumented code that doesn't make sense, one thing you can do is look at why someone wrote it in the first place. Here's the commit that adds the `nodeType` check:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/3c7f2af81d877b24a5e5b6488e78621fcf96b265

Judging by the test that they added with it, it's to support `form` elements, which it will treat as an array of controls.